# Disable the Windows 10 firewall for just one network adapter

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall

I want to disable the Windows 10 firewall for just one network adapter on my computer. I want to leave the firewall enabled for the other network adapters. How do I do this?

Will I be regularly prompted to re-enable the firewall for the adapter? If so, can I disable the prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open windows firewall (`wf.msc`) and in the center pane, click on `Windows Firewall Properties`. In the dialog box that opens, for each profile (domain, private, public) click *Customize* for the `Protected network connections`. There you can enable/disable windows firewall for a given network connection.

Answer (score 6):

**PowerShell solution**: open PowerShell with administrator rights and enter

`Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile` <*profile*> `-DisabledInterfaceAliases "`<*adapter name*>`"`

where <*adapter name*> is the name of the interface, as displayed in the list returned by

`Get-NetAdapter -Name * | Format-List`

and <*profile*> is a list of profiles from {"Domain", "Private" and "Public"}.

**Example**: to exclude the Virtual Box internal adapter from the Public Firewall Profile rules

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public -DisabledInterfaceAliases "VirtualBox Host-Only Network"
```

**Note**: to undo this command, you need to provide an empty string array as parameter for *DisabledInterfaceAliases* . In PowerShell empty array is `@()`. Example:

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public -DisabledInterfaceAliases @()
```